# Java - Summing up values of Array except a specific section

Tags: java, arrays, sum, limit

I got the task to sum up all values of an array except a section that starts with a 6 until the next 7 appears. Values after the 7 shall again be added to my sum.

Here's one of my solutions:

```
        if(nums == null){
            return 0;
        }else if(nums.length == 0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            int sum = 0;
            int countTill7 = 0;
            boolean six = false;

            for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
                if(nums[i] != 6){
                    sum += nums[i];
                }else if(nums[i] == 6){
                    six = true;
                    countTill7++;
                }else if(six == true && nums[i - 1] == 7){
                    six = false;
                    sum += nums[i];
                }

            }

            return sum;
        }
```

I can't find the problem..

Comment: You posted a question with a solution. How can we help?

Comment: The solution he posted is wrong

Comment: what is a `section that starts with 6`? every number that start´s with `6`, like `64` or and index that does start with `6`?

Comment: You can use continue to exclude 6-7 cases

Comment: Just to make sure - in the array `1 6 1 7 1 6 1 7 1`, should both `6 1 7` sections be skipped or just the first one?

Comment: @ZigZag i agree with Eran, because what i post will skip only first pair of 6...7 next pair should be calculated into sum, so be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I sumed up all values of an array except a section that starts with a 6 until the next 7 appears

```
package codingbat.array3;

public class Sum67
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    }

    /**
     * Return the sum of the numbers in the array, 
     * except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and
     * extending to the next 7 
     * (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). 
     * Return 0 for no numbers.
     *
     * sum67({1, 2, 2}) → 5
     * sum67({1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7}) → 5
     * sum67({1, 1, 6, 7, 2}) → 4
     */
    public int sum67(int[] nums) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        boolean got6 = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            if (6 == nums[i])
            {
                got6 = true;
            }
            else if (got6 && 7 == nums[i])
            {
                got6 = false;
            }
            else if (!got6)
            {
                sum += nums[i];        
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that OP wants at-least including the 7 'else if(six == true && nums[i - 1] == 7){
                    six = false;
                    sum += nums[i];
                }
'

Comment: @Neijwiert ty for the comment. I re-read what OP asks several times. Now you do the same :). OP asks "**values after 7** _should_ again _be added_".

Comment: yeah it is kind of weird the way OP asks it hehe. I think it could mean either way. But if only the first range should be skipped, then it works. But I was mislead that OP had nums[I - 1] == 7 and then does a sum addition.

Comment: @Willmore what about if 6 again encounter after 7 then.... i think in that case you will skip that too,

Comment: section [6, <other ints> ,7] is skipped

Comment: @Willmore Thank you, your answer was quite helpful. I'm sorry if my question wasn't precise but I'm glad that you understood my problem.

Comment: @ZigZag you are welcome! I am glad that I helped you with an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use state variables to indicate whether we are in a "6 to 7" block:

```
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < nums.length) {
  // Sum up the numbers until we find a 6.
  while (i < nums.length && nums[i] != 6) {
    sum += nums[i];
    ++i;
  }
  if (i < nums.length) {
    // The i-th number is a 6.
    // Increase i until the (i-1)-th number is a 7,
    // since then i points to the next number we
    // should add from.
    do {
      ++i;
    } while (i <= nums.length && nums[i - 1] != 7);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that with 3 loops?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just miss a boolean

turn

```
if(nums[i] != 6)
```

to

```
if(nums[i] != 6 && !six)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something likewise,

```
boolean flag = true, oneTimeDone = false;

  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
      if(flag){
         if(nums[i] == 6 && !oneTimeDone){
                    flag = false;
         }else{  
           sum += nums[i];
         }  
     }else{
            if(nums[i] == 7){
                  oneTimeDone = true;
                  flag = true;
            }

     }
  }
```

Update Out-put :

[image]

Comment: @Neijwiert kindly see output, 'oneTimeDone' variable does a lot... think if 6-incoming after 7 then it should be count.

Comment: I apologize, I for some reason thought OP wanted range 6-7 and exclude everything else. I didn't downvote though.

Comment: No need to use oneTimeDone variable

Comment: it's required.... if 6 encounter after 7 then, questioner haven't said that every 6....7 should be skip... it's required if want to count 6 after 7 appear

Comment: Nice gif btw, didn't know you could embed that.

Answer (score -1):

```
        int sum = 0;
        int countTill7 = 0;
        boolean six = false, seven=false;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            if(six==false && seven==false){
                if(nums[i]==6) six=true;
                else sum += nums[i];
            }else if(six==false || seven==false) {
                if(nums[i]==7) seven=true;
            }else {
                sum += nums[i];
            }
        }

        return sum;
```

Comment: Again, There's no need for two flags, willmore solution is totally enough